# Change form submission from GET to POST PHP

Tags: php, post, get, http-post, http-get

I'm working on big site and it has filtering of cars in it. I'll explain how the form filtering works:

so the user chooses filter options, car number and so and presses go, which makes GET request to server (php) i've changed every variable from $_GET to $_POST and changed form submission method, the problem is that when form returns big number of items it might have more than 2 pages, so when the user clicks on second or third page all this code does is add page number to the request like this: www.example.com/GET_REQUEST_VARIABLES -> www.example.com/pagenumber&GET_REQUEST_VARIABLES. that way server returns second page items and so.

but when i send post request, it isn't saved in the url so server doesn't know what to return,

can you help me solve this problem?

i can explain better if you ask questions i don't know if i explained clearly here

Comment: Are you saying that when you go to page 2, you lose all the options that were saved in $_POST? OR That when you go to page 2, there is no page 2 because the page number is not being appended to the URL?

Comment: when i go to page 2 server loses all the variables i've sent before using post, it appends page number but it doesn't add those variables sent from post because its another request

Comment: Could you save the $_POST variables in a $_SESSION variable? This would allow them to carry from page to page. Otherwise, sounds like you would need to POST the information again each time. I'd recommend $_SESSION.

Comment: ckimbrell is right, either $_SESSION or post them each page change.

Comment: i taught about it too but don't know if thats a good idea or not, i'm front end developer but my company doesn't have backend developer so i do the backend job too :)

Comment: The answer below from @Native Coder is pretty on point. Unless the data is sensitive, using $_GET would be fine here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you are using POST instead of GET? Using GET is more SEO friendly in this case. And since you aren't sending sensitive data in the form submission, I don't see a reason to use POST. Another advantage of using GET is that you can directly link to search results. (For instance, if I search for a Honda Fit, and want to show my wife, I have a direct link to the page)

(Look [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) for a bullet-point explination of the difference bewteen POST and GET).

To answer your other question, POST does not use the URL. Only GET does  So if you need the form data to be serialized into the URL, you'll need to use GET. Since you changed the form submission method to POST, you'll need to change the server side logic as well to accommodate. I can't be of much use without knowing what server-side technology you are using. Assuming you are using PHP, you could start [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

If you aren't much for MAN pages, just change all the $_GET['fieldName'] calls in PHP to $_POST['fieldName']

You could always POST the first page, and use GET ONLY for the page number. In the form you would just do this

```
    <form method="post" action="www.foo.com/search?page=1">
```

Then you can store your POSTed variables into the $_SESSION super-global. BOOM. POSTed pagination. It would be a breeze to render it on the fly with PHP

```
$nextPageURL = 'www.foo.com/search?page=' . $_GET['page'] + 1;
if($_GET['page'] !== '0'){
    $lastPageURL = 'www.foo.com/search?page=' . $_GET['page'] - 1;
}
```

Comment: reason i'm using post request is that get request is sometimes getting too big and server returns "big url" error

Comment: yeah you're right but what if request gets bigger in future?

Comment: you could always increase its length again if it becomes an issue down the line.

Comment: I woudln't. You know, it occurs to me that this limit is quite large. Any way you can show me the URL generated from a search? I feel like there has to be a way to shorten it....

Comment: how do i show you? i cant post it here its too big :D

Comment: You know what, I feel dumb. I just edited my answer, see it

Comment: i've found piece of code that made this enormous get request, i'll try to fix it and if i can't handle it ill do it how you explain, thank you :)

Comment: Feel free to IM me, if you need help. I love PHP. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123270/discussion-between-native-coder-and-nikagar4).